# Nvidia 9400M vs Intel 4000HD

Tags: graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I have done some searching on google and found some tests saying 4000HD is a great improvement over previous generation etc. Although I didn't get any tests that compared it with dedicated cards.

Could any of you guys that are more into hardware tell me if 4000 HD will be better than nvidia 9400M?

The first is part of the new MBP 13" with 2.9GHZ i7 while nvidia is part of 2009 MBP 13" 2.53GZH dual core 2.

p.s. I only play D3 on my laptop. Don't care about graphics as long as fps is good. currently with nvidia its really bad.It is listed as low performance on blizzard site, and intel 4000 too.
http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/D3supportedvideo

Comment: Welcome! Shopping/buying recommendations are off-topic, as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).  Also, questions asking which is "better" is subjective, and also off-topic.

Comment: @techie007 The OP doesn't seem to be asking for shopping advice. Also, the question "which card has better performance" can be answered objectively based on data from synthetic and game benchmarks.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but I think it starts getting into "Too localized" then, as comparing two specific cards is a little narrow.  But hey, I'm not the only one who gets to vote. I was just offering my reasoning. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Notebookcheck.net's mobile graphics cards benchmark list](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Mobile-Graphics-Cards-Benchmark-List.844.0.html), the [HD 4000](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000.69168.0.html) is #181 and the [9400M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-9400M-G.11949.0.html) is #302. You can also compare more detailed benchmark results on their individual pages.

In [Passmark's video card benchmark list](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net), the [HD 4000](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=Intel%20HD%204000) scores 635 and the [9400M](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce%209400M%20G) scores 301.

So objectively, the HD 4000 will be much more powerful than the 9400M, and according to Notebookcheck.net should be able to get ~60 or ~27 fps in Diablo 3 on low and medium settings, respectively.

Comment: As suggested by the benchmark, the improvement is clearly visible. With low graphics I dont even get high temps and game works fine with med and some high settings.